# Fix PDF encoding

Tags: pdf, character-encoding

I have Arabic PDF Files and it seems that there are something wrong in its encoding .

When I try to search in the PDF for word inside it , it didn't find results

when I try to export the pdf contents to Excel using other programs it export data in a strange encoding

When I copy the data in the PDF to notepad , Notepad display strange encoding.

I am developing solution which will use these PDFs (about 950 file) so I must found a way to fix encoding.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you please share a link to one of your files?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I've never edited an Arabic file.

How did you export the .pdf contents to Excel?

You **cannot** directly open a .pdf file neither with Word/Excel/Wordpad nor Notepad,
that *strange* encoding you're seeing most probably is the specific encoding of a selected font resource.

You can use this 
[this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DetectEncoding.aspx)
tool to detect the encoding

but I really advise you to read the bare minimum about
[Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html)

From then on, considering the amount of files involved, a good solution seems to be 
[PyODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter)

For a smaller amount of files,
[Free PDF to Word Converter](http://www.hellopdf.com/download.php) will take care of your needs:

Comment: Dear Joao ,My main problem is to fix PDF file , when I open it in any PDF reader I can read it easily but when I search for any word I see it tells me "no results found"

Comment: But did you already confirmed what encoding those .pdf are using?Check this question, maybe it'll put you on track: http://superuser.com/questions/119393/search-pdfs-with-non-standard-character-encodings

Comment: yes this is exactly my situation , Thanks